Repeated-Measurements Analysis with Cross Correlation
I am trying to find the cause-and-effect relationship between water release from dams and downstream temperature. I have a data frame containing all of the temperature measurements from various sites downstream and the tailwater gauge (see below).
dput(head(SaltData))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1709942400, 1709943300, 1709944200, 
1709945100, 1709946000, 1709946900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), S1 = c(12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 
12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 12.78154296875), S2 = c(12.86734375, 
12.86734375, 12.86734375, 12.910244140625, 12.86734375, 12.824443359375
), S3 = c(12.223837890625, 12.223837890625, 12.26673828125, 12.26673828125, 
12.223837890625, 12.26673828125), S4 = c(7.8908984375, 7.847998046875, 
7.8908984375, 7.80509765625, 7.847998046875, 7.847998046875), 
    S5 = c(10.464921875, 10.507822265625, 10.507822265625, 10.507822265625, 
    10.55072265625, 10.507822265625), S6 = c(11.280029296875, 
    11.3229296875, 11.3229296875, 11.280029296875, 11.3229296875, 
    11.280029296875), S7 = c(11.3229296875, 11.3229296875, 11.3229296875, 
    11.365830078125, 11.3229296875, 11.365830078125), S8 = c(12.309638671875, 
    12.309638671875, 12.26673828125, 12.3525390625, 12.3525390625, 
    12.309638671875), S9 = c(10.808125, 10.808125, 10.851025390625, 
    10.808125, 10.89392578125, 10.89392578125), S10 = c(11.06552734375, 
    11.06552734375, 11.06552734375, 11.151328125, 11.194228515625, 
    11.151328125), S11 = c(10.9797265625, 10.9797265625, 10.9797265625, 
    10.9797265625, 11.06552734375, 11.022626953125), GaugeTemp = c(8.2, 
    8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2), GaugeHeight = c(70.83, 70.84, 70.84, 
    70.85, 70.83, 70.83)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

After asking a previous question, I have been notified of the data structure. What I was doing was a correlation between the downstream site and tailwater gauge, but that was not giving me a pattern that seemed correct (correlation was increasing with each downstream site, which should actually be the opposite of what should be seen). I now realize that I have repeated measurements data and would like to perform some sort of cross-correlation between the two. I realize I need to lag the data in order to account for the water's travel time downstream to each site. I just want to know if this would be a good way to analyze the data to show the direct effect of the dam release (tailwater gauge) on downstream temperature or if another test would be better. Thanks!
